# How to install libssh2 on Ubuntu / RStudio Server

Tags: r, ubuntu, libssh2

For my droplet RStudio Server running Ubuntu I want to use SFTP, but need to install / enabled libssh2 in order to do so.

I have tried to follow both https://libin007.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/install-libssh2/ and http://englanders.us/~jason/howtos.php?howto=libssh2 in order to install libssh2, but every time I run libcurlVersion() I get this result:

```
> libcurlVersion()
[1] "7.35.0"
attr(,"ssl_version")
[1] "OpenSSL/1.0.1f"
attr(,"libssh_version")
[1] ""
attr(,"protocols")
 [1] "dict"   "file"   "ftp"    "ftps"   "gopher" "http"   "https"  "imap"   "imaps"  "ldap"   "ldaps"  "pop3"   "pop3s"  "rtmp"   "rtsp"  
[16] "smtp"   "smtps"  "telnet" "tftp"
```

So even though I have installed libssh2 (or at least I think I have) R can’t find it.

My question is, how do I make R find libssh2/install it so it finds it?

---

**Update:**

I didn't fix it, but since I want to move a data file from one droplet server to another, I had a look at Rsync and it does the trick. For anyone interested!

Comment: I fixed a typo in your title. By R-server (which does not exist) did you mean RStudio Server? Or did you mean Simon's Rserve?

Comment: RStudio Server - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly be confusing issues?

If you want to talk to your server via SFTP from the outside, you need to run a SSH daemon.  This has nothing to with R -- do

```
 sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

or maybe just

```
 sudo apt-get install openssh-sftp-server
```

Folks often have issues building `curl` as a client package, but that has nothing to do with how your server responds to outside traffic. As such, you check of `libcurlVersion()` is not meaningful for the question at hand.

Comment: I may very well be confusing issues or just confused in general ;)
Tried to run ‘sudo apt-get install openssh-server’ but it is already installed. Also, I can access the server though filezilla / SFTP and when I try to access the server though my desktop R-studio there is no problem. The problem only accrues when I try to access the server from another R-server.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for installing the extension package on Debian systems:

> sudo apt-get install libssh2-php
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Just it!